# Equality of contour integrals in Stein & Shakarchi's of Prime Number Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, contour-integration

I am studying the proof of the prime number theorem in Stein & Shakarchi's **Complex Analysis**, and am not sure about the justification of a particular equality.

The equality I'm interested in is equation (7) in the screenshots below. In particular, I don't understand the sentence "Since $F$ is regular in that region, and its decrease at infinity is rapid enough, the assertion (7) is established." Are the authors referring to some uncited result about the growth of a holomorphic function and its relation to integrals around contours?

[image]

[image]

I really appreciate any help establishing this result!

Comment: what saying "the integrals over the contours are equal" actually means is "make a box out of the given contours (so with sides the given contours and make it finite by adding in a top (/bottom) bit), so that the integral around this box is zero by the residue theorem, then show that this top bit goes to zero as you make the box infinite".  i don't like the sound of this comment as i re-read it, but it's all i can say without writing maths... did it make sense?

Comment: So you're saying that the idea here is to add horizontal lines on each contour, then show that because of the given bound on F(s), the integral over those horizontal lines will go to zero as their imaginary part goes to infinity (the imaginary part being given by t)?

Comment: yep, exactly that

Comment: I see, thanks so much! I should have seen that, but I guess my complex analysis is a little rusty. If you want to post this as a short answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: welcome:)  oh ye sure, will do so tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I said in the comments what you need to do is make a box, apply the Residue Theorem, and push a side of the box to infinity.  Precisely, and in maybe too much detail (but hey maybe it's useful for someone sometime and that's why we're here), this means the following:

As you say, $c>1$.  For $R>T$ denote by $\mathcal B_R$ the box with sides
\[ \overbrace {(c+iT,c+Ri)}^{\text {right side}}\cup \overbrace {(c+Ri,1+Ri)}^{\text {top side}}\cup \overbrace {(1+Ri,1+iT)}^{\text {left side}}\cup \overbrace {(1+iT,c+iT)}^{\text {bottom side}},\]
and it's best to think of $R$ as large.  Since $F(s)$ is holomorphic in a region strictly containing this box (probably not terribly unwise to note this uses $\zeta (s)\not =0$ on the line $\sigma =1$) then the Residue Theorem says
\[ \int _{\mathcal B_R}F(s)ds=0\]
or said differently
\[ \int _{c+iT}^{c+Ri}F(s)ds=\left (\int _{1+Ri}^{c+Ri}+\int _{1+iT}^{1+Ri}+\int _{c+iT}^{1+iT}\right )F(s)ds.\]
Now we show the first integral on the RHS -the one over the top side of the box- is small.  Since on $(1+Ri,c+Ri)$ certainly $F(s)\ll _x1/t=1/R$, we have
\[ \int _{1+Ri}^{c+Ri}F(s)ds\ll _x\frac {1}{R}\int _1^cd\sigma \ll _c\frac {1}{R}\]
i.e.
\[ \lim _{R\rightarrow \infty }\int _{1+Ri}^{c+Ri}F(s)ds=0.\]
Therefore
\[ \int _{c+iT}^{c+i\infty }F(s)ds=\lim _{R\rightarrow \infty }\int _{c+iT}^{c+Ri}F(s)ds=\lim _{R\rightarrow \infty }\left (\int _{1+Ri}^{c+Ri}+\int _{1+iT}^{1+Ri}+\int _{c+iT}^{1+iT}\right )F(s)ds=\left (\int _{1+iT}^{1+i\infty }+\int _{c+iT}^{1+iT}\right )F(s)ds.\]
Doing a similar argument in the lower half of the plane should give us
\[ \int _{c-i\infty }^{c-iT}F(s)ds=\left (\int _{1-i\infty }^{1-iT}+\int _{1-iT}^{c-iT}\right )F(s)ds\]
which allows us to conclude
\[ \left (\int _{c-i\infty }^{c-iT}+\int _{c-Ti}^{c+iT}+\int _{c+iT}^{c+i\infty }\right )F(s)ds=\left (\int _{1-i\infty }^{1-iT}+\int _{1-iT}^{c-iT}+\int _{c-iT}^{c+iT}+\int _{c+iT}^{1+iT}+\int _{1+iT}^{1+i\infty }\right )F(s)ds\]
i.e.
\[ \int _{c-i\infty }^{c+i\infty }F(s)ds=\int _{\gamma (T)}F(s)ds.\]